# Show that none of the five subgroups of order $2$ in $D_5$ are normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Show that none of the five subgroups of order $2$ in $D_5$  are normal.

Can I say $\alpha^2 H\neq H\alpha^2$ for $\alpha^2\in D_5$, with $\alpha^2$ having an order of $2$

Comment: I guess that depends on what $H$ is. Also which $\alpha\in D_5$ gives an $\alpha^2$ of order $2$?

Comment: I thought it was the rotations but I think I am mistaken.

Comment: Hint. The rotations have order 5; the reflections have order 2. Work out the geometry of $ABA^-1$ when $A$ is a rotation and $B$ is a reflection. Or do this calculation expressing the group elements as permutations of the vertices.

Comment: As @EthanBolker notes in his comment on my answer, you should probably provide some more context so you get an appropriate-level answer. If you're happy to have some that use whatever is available, of course, feel free to leave things as-is. Cheers!

Comment: A normal subgroup of order 2 is central. The quotient would have order 5, so be cyclic. What do you know about groups who have cyclic central quotients?

Comment: The answer of Steve D is the most elegant one, a proof with hands down, without any appeal to Sylow Theory. +1 from me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sylow's theorem indicates that if $P_2$ is normal it is unique. Since you have already stated $\#P_2>1$ that is sufficient.

Comment: Correct, of course - but I suspect the OP hasn't reached the Sylow theorems yet in his study of group theory.